# Reason for use of signed char to represent network address?

Tags: c, network-programming, ip-address

struct hostent (under both windows and unices) that's used for example with gethostbyname() et al. keeps the dotted addresses using a pointer to signed `char`.

What's the benefit of this when it's known in advance that addresses can and mostly do contain numbers > 127, and that they're ultimately represented unsigned? Is there any benefit from having signability, any edge case covered? Or is it just a historical baggage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it is just historical baggage - just like the functions using it.

Nowadays, it is recommended to use `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()` in order to be protocol-independent. `gethostbyname()` is obsolete, just like its counterpart `gethostbyaddr()`.

Comment: Was looking for some obscure edge-case but as you say there probably isn't.